# How to get flex items with different left/right padding to be the same width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've recreated my scenario in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r1txcufw/15/

```js
function showPixels() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("DIV");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(x[i].offsetWidth + ' px');
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    x[i].innerHTML = '';
    x[i].appendChild(node);
  }
}

window.onload = showPixels;
window.onresize = showPixels;
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.col {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.col div {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.no-left-padding {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='icon'>
    A
  </div>
  <div class='col no-left-padding'>
    Our Widths
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    Are different becasue of padding
  </div>
</div>
```

I just added first icon column for completeness. There can be more than two columns (div with class `col`) but the example has 2 . I want each of the columns to fill up the flexbox and still all be the same width even though one or more columns may have 0 left/right padding.

Comment: Here is a little [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ngawhbj1/) you can work on it

Comment: I don't understand which widths exactly you want to be the same especially in regards to padding. And what role does the icon play?

Comment: @RoToRa Temani answer already helped but the icon column is just a fixed width column. But I wanted the remaining columns 2+ of them to all be equal width even if one of them doesn't have left/right padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the padding and consider a negative `margin-left` for the first column:

```js
function showPixels() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement("DIV");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(x[i].offsetWidth + ' px');
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    x[i].innerHTML = '';
    x[i].appendChild(node);
  }
}

window.onload = showPixels;
window.onresize = showPixels;
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
  z-index:1;
}

.col {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis:0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.col div {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.no-left-padding {
  margin-left: -1rem !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='icon'>
    A
  </div>
  <div class='col no-left-padding'>
    Our Widths
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
    Are different becasue of padding
  </div>
</div>
```